# .htaccess bringing the url correctly

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am learning programming technology MVC
During construction of the .htaccess file i had trouble bringing in the the url

Where the address of the index :

```
C:\wamp\www\mvc\public\index.php
```

and the address of the .htaccess file is :

```
C:\wamp\www\mvc\.htaccess
```

And i used the following code to bring the url:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /mvc/public/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

And i used the following code to exploit the url:

```
if(isset($_GET['url']))
{
    return $url = explode('/',filter_var(rtrim($_GET['url'], '/'),FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
```

When i insert the following address, for example:

```
http: // localhost / mvc / public / sami / ahmad / sameer
```

The site re following matrix:

```
Array ([0] => public [1] => sami [2] => ahmad [3] => sameer)
```

I want to start from the matrix after the public folder ..

How can i do this ??

Comment: Just place this .htaccess in `mvc/public` folder

Comment: yeah it worked !! oh thanks man you know i was trying from 2 days .. that simple